# how to modify existing data, using if condition with JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm a novice programmer just learning JSON and want to ask a question
how to change data & print it

based on condition if score > 5, status changes from unposted to posted

```
let data = [
    {
        title: "The Only Guide You Need",
        score:8,
        status: "Posted"
    },
    {
        title: "The Advanced Guide To Archive",
        score:5,
        status: "Unposted"

    },
    {
        title: "In Defense of the Figurative Use of Literally.",
        score:6,
        status: "Unposted",
    },
]

console.log(data)
```

**thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop through each element. If the score is greater than 5, set `status` to `"Posted"`

```js
let data = [
    {
        title: "The Only Guide You Need",
        score:8,
        status: "Posted"
    },
    {
        title: "The Advanced Guide To Archive",
        score:5,
        status: "Unposted"

    },
    {
        title: "In Defense of the Figurative Use of Literally.",
        score:6,
        status: "Unposted",
    },
]

data = data.map((current) => {
  if (current.score > 5) current.status = "Posted";
  return current;
});

console.log(data)
```